# Django Exception -- Djangoblog

Tags: django

I'm trying to configure djangoblog for exception handling but get the below msg,

Error:
ImproperlyConfigured: Middleware module "djangodblog" does not define a "DBLogMiddleware" class

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'djangodblog.DBLogMiddleware', 
)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djangodblog',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Comment: When does this crash show up? During `syncdb`? During `runserver`? How did you install the app? Is it up to date? Please give us more information. I just tested this configuration on a fresh django 1.4 virtualenv and I get no problems. The class is defined in that middleware.

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer after Googling only: shouldn't it be `djangodblog.middleware.DBLogMiddleware` not `djangodblog.DBLogMiddleware`?

http://nullege.com/codes/search/djangodblog.middleware.DBLogMiddleware